# Block keyboard in Emacs from input

Tags: emacs, elisp, kiosk

How to block keyboard from input in Emacs?

I want to have a feature of making input impossible in Emacs. I will bind this to some specific key combination and only restore input functionality only pressing this key combination again. I think this feature is called "kiosk" in some applications.

If there is no package for that already, i'm interested in ideas or elisp code to implement it.

Answer (score 4):

`(setq overriding-terminal-local-map (make-sparse-keymap))` will make your keyboard completely inoperative.  And

```
(setq overriding-terminal-local-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [?\C-c ?\C-c]
      (lambda () (interactive) (setq overriding-terminal-local-map nil)))
    map))
```

might be a good starting point.